# Scheduling one time tasks with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have to implement functionality that requires delayed sending of a message to a user once on a specific date, which can be anytime - from tomorrow till in a few months from now.

All our code is so far implemented as lambda functions.

I'm considering three options on how to implement this:

1. Create an entry in DynamoDB with hash key being date and range key being unique ID. Schedule lambda to run once a day and pick up all entries/tasks scheduled for this day, send a message for each of them.
2. Using SDK Create cloudwatch event rule with cron expression indicating single execution and make it invoke lambda function (target) with ID of user/message. The lambda would be invoked on a specific schedule with a specific user/message to be delivered.
3. Create a step function instance and configure it to sleep & invoke step with logic to send a message when the right moment comes.

Do you have perhaps any recommendation on what would be best practice to implement this kind of business requirement? Perhaps an entirely different approach?

Comment: If you care about the time then I like option 2, but if it's really just on a date rather than date/time, then yeah option 1 (or using S3 as suggested in the answer) where the items to send that day can be scanned once a day via a scheduled lambda seems perfectly adequate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It largely depends on scale. If you'll only have a few scheduled at any point in time then I'd use the CloudWatch events approach. It's very low overhead and doesn't involve running code and doing nothing.

If you expect a LOT of schedules then the DynamoDB approach is very possibly the best approach. Run the lambda on a fixed schedule, see what records have not yet been run, and are past/equal to current time. In this model you'll want to delete the records that you've already processed (or mark them in some way) so that you don't process them again. Don't rely on the schedule running at certain intervals and checking for records between the last time and the current time unless you are recording when the last time was (i.e. don't assume you ran a minute ago because you scheduled it to run every minute).

Step functions could work if the time isn't too far out. You can include a delay in the step that causes it to just sit and wait. The delays in step functions are just that, delays, not scheduled times, so you'd have to figure out that delay yourself, and hope it fires close enough to the time you expect it. This one isn't a bad option for mid to low volume.

Edit:
Step functions include a `wait_until` option on [wait states](https://states-language.net/spec.html#wait-state) now. This is a really good option for what you are describing.

Answer (score 1):

As of November 2022, the cleanest approach would be to use EventBridge Scheduler's one-time schedule.

> A one-time schedule will invoke a target only once at the date and time that you specify using a valid date, and a timestamp. EventBridge Scheduler supports scheduling in Universal Coordinated Time (UTC), or in the time zone that you specify when you create your schedule. You configure a one-time schedule using an at expression.

Here is an example using the AWS CLI:

```
aws scheduler create-schedule --schedule-expression "at(2022-11-30T13:00:00)" --name schedule-name \
--target '{"RoleArn": "role-arn", "Arn": "QUEUE_ARN", "Input": "TEST_PAYLOAD" }' \
--schedule-expression-timezone "America/Los_Angeles"
--flexible-time-window '{ "Mode": "OFF"}'
```

Reference: [Schedule types on EventBridge Scheduler - EventBridge Scheduler
User Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/scheduler/latest/UserGuide/schedule-types.html?icmpid=docs_console_unmapped#one-time)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using DynamoDB I would suggest to use s3. Store the message and time to trigger as key value pairs.

1. S3 to store the date and time as key value store.
2. Use s3 lambda trigger to create the cloudwatch rules that would target specific lambda's etc
3. You can even schedule a cron to a lambda that will read the files from s3 and update the required cron for the message to be sent.

Hope so this is in line with your requirements

Comment: This is quite interesting but I'm not sure if I understand the role of S3 in this setup. I could just create cloudwatch rule in my code which is executing at the time when I want to do this scheduling (my solution no 2)? What would be benefit of using s3?

Comment: If I understand correctly, CloudWatch (now EventBridge) allows only a limited amount of scheduled tasks at any given point in time. S3 doesn't have a storage limit. I hope you get my point.